# How to recursively convert keys of Ruby Hashes that are symbols to String

Tags: ruby, recursion, hash

Suppose I have following hash or nested hash:

```
h = { :a1 => { :b1 => "c1" },
      :a2 => { :b2 => "c2"},
      :a3 => { :b3 => "c3"} }
```

I want to create a method that takes hash as a parameter and recursively convert all the keys (keys that are symbol eg. `:a1`) to String (eg. `"a1"`). So far I have come up with the following method which doesn't work and returns `{"a1"=>{:b1=>"c1"}, "a2"=>{:b2=>"c2"}, "a3"=>{:b3=>"c3"}}`.:

```
def stringify_all_keys(hash)
    stringified_hash = {}
    hash.each do |k, v|
        stringified_hash[k.to_s] = v
        if v.class == Hash
            stringify_all_keys(stringified_hash[k.to_s])
        end
    end
    stringified_hash
end
```

What am I doing wrong and how do a get all the keys converted to string like this:

```
{"a1"=>{"b1"=>"c1"}, "a2"=>{"b2"=>"c2"}, "a3"=>{"b3"=>"c3"}}
```

Comment: Quick, dirty, and totally inefficient: `JSON.parse(h.to_json)`

Comment: Awesome!!! Worked! Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using `ActiveSupport` already or are open to using it, then [deep_stringify_keys](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_stringify_keys) is what you're looking for.

```
hash = { person: { name: 'Rob', age: '28' } }

hash.deep_stringify_keys
# => {"person"=>{"name"=>"Rob", "age"=>"28"}}
```

Comment: This is preferred to my answer, if you are on a stack w/activesupport. The only thing to be aware of is that any symbols inside of arrays anywhere in the hash will also be converted to strings.

Comment: Uhm, no, they won't: `{ 'foo' => ['a', 'b'] }.deep_symbolize_keys
#=> {:foo=>["a", "b"]}`. `deep_symbolize_keys` uses `deep_transform_keys` internally, which as the name implies only works on the keys, not the values of the hash.

Comment: I stand corrected. That being said, keys which are arrays of symbols will be converted to arrays to strings, which is not what I said but is a difference from the specifics of the implementation in the question.
edit: actually, i take that back, array keys are just straight up to_s'd:
`{ [:a,:z] => [:b,:c] }.deep_stringify_keys # {"[:a, :z]"=>[:b, :c]}`

Comment: `deep_stringify_keys == deep_transform_keys(&:to_s)`, so no surprises there.

Comment: Embarrassingly I was surprised, the transform is only deep on the value side. IMO a deep operation implies propagating everywhere _shrug_, apologies for my ignorance.

Answer (score 6):

Quick'n'dirty if your values are basic objects like strings, numbers, etc:

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse(JSON.dump(hash))
```

Comment: The advantage to this solution vs the one by Michael Kohl is that this addresses DateTime objects.  (well, really any object).

Answer (score 3):

Didn't test this, but looks about right:

```
def stringify_all_keys(hash)
  stringified_hash = {}
  hash.each do |k, v|
    stringified_hash[k.to_s] = v.is_a?(Hash) ? stringify_all_keys(v) : v
  end
  stringified_hash
end
```

Answer (score 0):

using plain ruby code, the below code could help.
you can monkey patched it to the ruby Hash, to use it like this `my_hash.deeply_stringfy_keys`
however, I do not recommend monkey batching ruby.

you can adjust the method to provide the `deeply_strigify_keys!` (bang) version of it.

in case you want to make a different method witch does not stringify recursively, or to control the level of stringifying then consider re-writing the below method logic so you can have it written better with considering the other variation mentioned above.

```
def deeply_stringify_keys(hash)
  stringified_hash = {}
  hash.each do |k, v|
    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      stringified_hash[k.to_s] = deeply_stringify_keys(v)
    elsif v.is_a?(Array)
      stringified_hash[k.to_s] = v.map {|i| i.is_a?(Hash)? deeply_stringify_keys(i) : i}
    else
      stringified_hash[k.to_s] = v
    end
  end
  stringified_hash
end
```